# Shiny App: Cannot Generate the Correct Plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The solution to my problem must be a one-liner, but I am making my baby steps with shiny.
Please consider the example at

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html

Which I have modified so that it uses ggplot2 to generate the plot (and a scatterplot instead of a barplot). I paste the code below. Obviously there is a bug since ggplot2 does not plot the values of each columns on the y axis. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(shiny)


 # Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
 # package (which generally comes preloaded).
 library(datasets)

 nn <- row.names(WorldPhones) %>% as.numeric

 ww <- WorldPhones %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    mutate(year=nn) %>%
    select(year, everything())

 mycolnames <- colnames(WorldPhones)

 # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
 ui <- fluidPage(    

     # Give the page a title
     titlePanel("Telephones by region"),

     # Generate a row with a sidebar
     sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
     sidebarPanel(
     selectInput("region", "Region:", 
              choices=mycolnames),
      hr(),
      helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")
     ),

     # Create a spot for the barplot
     mainPanel(
      plotOutput("phonePlot")  
    )

    )
    )


 # Define a server for the Shiny app
  server <- function(input, output) {

  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
   output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({

  ## plot(ww[,input$region]*1000, 
   ##         main=input$region,
   ##         ylab="Number of Telephones",
   ##      xlab="Year")

  ggplot(ww, aes(x=year, y=input$region
                      )) +
  geom_point(size=3, shape=1, stroke=2)  
  })
   }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing a length 1 character vector here `y=input$region`.  You could do this to actually pass the column:

```
ggplot(ww, aes(x=year, y=ww[[input$region]])) +
  geom_point(size=3, shape=1, stroke=2)
```